# when you are to non-culturally detect the presence of E. coli in the soil from a cow pasture?

Tags: microbiology, homework

> You are to non-culturally detect the presence of E. coli in the soil from a cow pasture. You do this by extracting the total DNA from a sample of the soil and PCR amplifying with E. coli-specific primers that bind to a gene only found in E. coli that amplify a region of the DNA 167 bp long. Propose a postive sample that could be tested alongside your experimental sample.
>
> A. Known Shigella DNA
>
> B. Water
>
> C. Number of Injections
>
> D. Muscle DNA
>
> E. Known E. coli DNA

I think the answer is (E) Known E. coli DNA. That would be the positive control in this context. For a positive control, you need something that you would know the response for. E. coli specific primers would amplify the known E. coli DNA. Water is obviously wrong. I could be wrong. Am I missing something?

Comment: To the homework close voter: this user has made an attempt to answer, so has fulfilled the requirements of the homework policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. The question is asking for a positive sample that would be amplified by *E. coli* specific primers. Known *E. coli* DNA would do the trick.

Comment: @user50592 you're welcome. If you'd like to mark this as the answer, click the gray checkmark next to it. I would also recommend you take the [tour] and visit [help] to learn about this stack exchange site.